# using Grep to output a string

Tags: string, grep, wildcard

When running a command I get an output that outputs a chart:

```js
+---------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Key     | Value                                                |
+---------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Address | longstringofcharacters |
+---------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Name    | word1-word2-word3                              |
+---------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

I can grep Name to get the line that contains the word `Name`.

What do I grep to output just the string of `word1-word2-word3` only?

I've tried `grep '*-*-*'` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU grep, you can use a PCRE regex based solution like

```sh
grep -oP '^\h*\|\h*Name\h*\|\h*\K\S+' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/qA28cH) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IaLCUO/1).

- `-o` - outputs matches only
- `P` - enables the PCRE regex engine
- `^` - start of string
- `\h*\|\h*` - a `|` char enclosed with optional horizontal whitespaces
- `Name` - a word `Name`
- `\h*\|\h*` - a `|` char enclosed with optional horizontal whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards text matched so far
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars.

With a GNU `awk`:

```sh
awk -F'[|[:space:]]+' '$2 == "Name"{print $3}' file
```

Set the field separator to a `[|[:space:]]+` regex that matches one or more `|` chars or whitespaces, check if Group 2 equals `Name` and grab Field 3.

With any `awk` (if you need to extract a string like `nonwhitespaces(-nonwhitespaces)+`):

```sh
awk 'match($0, /[^ -]+(-[^ -]+)+/) { print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) }' file
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/XrHTrA).

Comment: Thank you this was the perfect answer. Already up and running!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using awk is:

```
awk '/Name/{ print $4 }'
```

The `/Name/` section is how awk "greps". The `{ print $4 }` bit says print the fourth space delimited word.